# Is it possible to connect history of two files in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I have two files stored in TFS (FileA, FileB). `FileB` was created as **a copy** of `FileA` in a different folder (VS project). `FileB` was then edited and gained history, `FileA` was deleted. If I am looking for an ancient change I need to know about the existence of `FileA` and look into its history.

Is it possible to create some connection of histories between these two files (other then writing to the first changeset "look to FileA")?

Comment: If FileB was branched from File A then the history of File B would show the updates of file A up till the branch point.  If you just made a copy of File a and then added that copy to TFS, there is no relation between the 2

Comment: @MBulava: I know that there is no relation. I am looking for a possibility to create it.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.  However if you know where FileA used to exist in TFS you can pull the change history on the folder itself find the delete of FileA and then pull the changeset from just before the delete and pull the history from FileA

Comment: I found the problem about two years after deletion of FileA. So both files has its history but that of FileB is more important.